# Updating JLabel everytime Frame's panel is updated

Tags: java, swing

How can I update JLabel `Count #0` to `Count #1` as continued, at topPanel in Frame?

Initially it is `Count #0` and as the operation performs further it changes to `Count #1`.

OUTPUT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFPx.png) it is showing `Count #0` but it should be `Count #2` as the grey box is on second level, Similarly [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN9VR.png) it should show `Count #5`, as its on fifth level from top.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class Count {
    private int num;
    
    public Count() {
        this.num = 1;
    }
    
    // Generate Next Number
    public void generate(int currentNumber) {
        this.num = currentNumber;
        this.num += 1;
    }
    
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.num;
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel {
    private final BufferedImage image;
    private Count count;
    
    public Panel() {
        this.image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        this.count = new Count();
        Timer timer = new Timer(0, ae -> createImage(image));
        timer.setDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void createImage(BufferedImage image) {
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        
        int number = this.count.getNumber();
        
        // Set field on frame which will be added to bottomPanel
        for (int i = 0; i < (number * 20); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (number * 20); j++) {
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(i, j, 20, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.drawRect(i, j, 20, 20);
            }
        }
        
        // Generating next number
        this.count.generate(number);
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    
    public GUI() {
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        
        // Setting topPanel and Adding Label to topPanel
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        updateLabel(0);
        
        // Instructions for bottomPanel
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        
        // Adding the instructions to bottomPanel
        bottomPanel.add(panel);

        // Adding topPanel and bottomPanel to Frame
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }
    
    public void updateLabel(int number) {
        // Label - 1
        JLabel countLabel = new JLabel("CountLabel");
        countLabel.setText("   Count #" + number);
        countLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        countLabel.setBounds(10, 5, 300, 20);
        
        topPanel.add(countLabel);
    }
}

public class NumberPresentation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So, how should I start working so that the JLabel in topPanel keeps updating every time `Count` class `generate()` another number, and `generate()` is called in `Panel` class's `createImage()` function?

Thank You.

PS: The bottomPanel animation is good, I just want to know how I can work around with JLabel to update it everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a Callback oriented approach, this is very similar to how JButton's `addActionListener` works. Warning it's a bit long and might get messy if you abuse it, but it keeps your initial classes separation intact.

The idea is to add an `onUpdate` method to your Panel class that gets called every time the panel updates. And then to define what the action is when you create a panel.

For that, you will first need to declare an abstract class or interface with the methods you need, I choose generic names but feel free to customize

```java
interface Callback {
    public void action(int v);
}
```

We can now pass declare and pass an action method that takes an integer to any class, you just need to add a Callback field :

```java
class Panel extends JPanel {
    private final BufferedImage image;
    private Count count;
    private Callback onUpdate;

    public void setOnUpdateAction(Callback action) {
        this.onUpdate = action;
    }
```

You're free to choose where to call onUpdate, I made it after the next number is generated

```java
// Generating next number
this.count.generate(number);
onUpdate.action(this.count.getNumber());
repaint();
```

Your `Panel` class is now ready.

Now after creating your panel, just make a call to setOnUpdateAction

```java
panel.setOnUpdateAction(new Callback() {
    public void action(int v) {
        countLabel.setText("   Count #" + v);
    }
});
```

Since there is only one method and one instruction, you can use a shorter Lambda syntax similar to the one you used in the Timer

```java
panel.setOnUpdateAction(v -> countLabel.setText("   Count #" + v));
```

( I had to make the countLabel a field to access it inside GUI.)

And there you have it !

[image]

Here's the full modified code :

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class Count {
    private int num;

    public Count() {
        this.num = 1;
    }

    // Generate Next Number
    public void generate(int currentNumber) {
        this.num = currentNumber;
        this.num += 1;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.num;
    }
}

interface Callback {
    public void action(int v);
}

class Panel extends JPanel {
    private final BufferedImage image;
    private Count count;
    private Callback onUpdate;


    public void setOnUpdateAction(Callback action) {
        this.onUpdate = action;
    }

    public Panel() {
        this.image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        this.count = new Count();
        Timer timer = new Timer(0, ae -> createImage(image));
        timer.setDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void createImage(BufferedImage image) {
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        int number = this.count.getNumber();

        // Set field on frame which will be added to bottomPanel
        for (int i = 0; i < (number * 20); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (number * 20); j++) {
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(i, j, 20, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.drawRect(i, j, 20, 20);
            }
        }

        // Generating next number
        this.count.generate(number);
        onUpdate.action(this.count.getNumber());
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private JLabel countLabel;  // Made it a field to use after being created

    public GUI() {
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        // Setting topPanel and Adding Label to topPanel
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        updateLabel(0);

        // Instructions for bottomPanel
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        panel.setOnUpdateAction(new Callback() {
            public void action(int v) {
                countLabel.setText("   Count #" + v);
            }
        });

        // You can also use this lambda syntax ( since Callback has only 1 method to implement )
        // panel.setOnUpdateAction(v -> countLabel.setText("   Count #" + v));


        // Adding the instructions to bottomPanel
        bottomPanel.add(panel);

        // Adding topPanel and bottomPanel to Frame
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }

    public void updateLabel(int number) {
        // Label - 1
        countLabel = new JLabel("CountLabel");
        countLabel.setText("   Count #" + number);
        countLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        countLabel.setBounds(10, 5, 300, 20);

        topPanel.add(countLabel);
    }
}

public class NumberPresentation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```